# Getting lots of time outs and errors using Azure Managed Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, azure, azure-caching

I have an asp.net web application hosted using Azure Websites that uses Azure Managed Cache to retrieve and store cached objects. The application was working fine until recently when we started experiencing timeouts and errors:

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:The connection was terminated,
>   possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size
>   is greater than MaxBufferSize on server. Result of the request is
>   unknown.. Additional Information : The client was trying to
>   communicate with the server:
>   net.tcp://foo.cache.windows.net:22233.

and

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:The request timed out..
>   Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the
>   server: net.tcp://foo.cache.windows.net:22233

Looking at the stack trace of both errors they all point to the `cache.Get("key")` line, so I am not sure why it's saying `serialized Object size is greater than MaxBufferSize`. Furthermore, looking at the monitor tab of the Caching object shows the Avg Size in bytes of 204 KB (max 215), meaning that it is not hitting the MaxBufferSize of 8 MB allowed by Azure. Unless, that is not the default value.

The code is very straight forward:

```
DataCacheFactory cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
myCache = cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();
var retVal = myCache.Get("MyKey") as List<string>();
if (retVal == null)
{
  retVal = GetFromDB();
  myCache.Put("MyKey", retVal, TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0));
}
```

What am I missing here? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I just saw a thread on MSDN forums about the issues with Managed Cache Service. Though the Azure Status Site (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) shows the service to be healthy, I saw an issue when I went to history page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history. Could this be the cause of your problem?

Comment: @Vogel612 typo. Corrected it

Comment: @GauravMantri could be. How would I know if i'm affected by it?

Comment: May I suggest you speak with Azure Support to see if there're still issues with this service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue affecting some users of the Managed Cache Service.  For assistance, you can contact either Azure Support or the cache team directly at 'azurecache@microsoft.com'.